# return values from a struct

Tags: c

```
typedef struct Value{
    int id;
    char type;
    char a;
} Value;

void fooV(Value v){
    v.id = 10;
    v.type = 'L';
    v.a = 'R';
}

int main(void){
    Value v;
    Pointer p;
    int id = 5;
    char type = 't';
    char a = 'a';

    printf("id: %d, type: %c, a: %c \n",id,type,a);

    v.a = a;
    v.id = id;
    v.type = type;
    fooV(v);
    printf("id: %d, type: %c, a: %c \n",id,type,a);

}
```

on the fooV call, Local variable value is created ...
therefore no data in the caller will be updated
But what if I want to return the values from fooV? what should I add to fooV? Thanks

Comment: Just a note: structs, as everything else in C, are passed around by value. The value of a struct can be huge (in terms of `sizeof struct`) so passing pointers to structs is a good habit to get into.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to pass v in *by reference*, which is done using pointers in C:

```
void fooV(Value* v)
{
    (*v).id = 10;
    (*v).type = 'L';
    (*v).a = 'R';
}
```

Or use the -> shorthand operator:

```
void fooV(Value* v)
{
    v->id = 10;
    v->type = 'L';
    v->a = 'R';
}
```

And don't forget to pass v's address:

```
fooV(&v);
```

Comment: As an alternative, you could return a `Value` struct from `fooV()`: `Value fooV(Value v);` though it's probably less efficient.

Comment: I got it to work!!!!
but would you explain the difference between (*v).id = 10; and *(v).id = 10; for some reason, i think they are the same...

Comment: @metashockwave: The operator "." has higher precedence than the operator "*", so "*(v).id" and "*v.id" will both be interpreted as "*(v.id)". To get the intended meaning, that is to FIRST follow the pointer using "*", and THEN to get the "id" field in the struct, you need to write "(*v).id" or "v->id".

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to have a `fooV` function that returns a "constructed" `Value` struct, you can rewrite `fooV` as follows:

```
Value fooV() {
    Value v;
    v.id = 10;
    v.type = 'L';
    v.a = 'R';
    return v;
}
```

and you would call this function like:

```
Value v = fooV();
```

Otherwise, if you need a function that modifies a `Value` struct that you already have, you have two options:  you either need to change the return type of `fooV`:

```
Value fooV(Value v){
    v.id = 10;
    v.type = 'L';
    v.a = 'R';
    return v;
}
```

in which case you would call it like:

```
v = fooV(v);
```

or change fooV to accept a pointer to a `Value`:

```
void fooV(Value* v){
    v->id = 10;
    v->type = 'L';
    v->a = 'R';
}
```

in which case you would call it like:

```
fooV(&v);
```

Comment: Wouldn't your first example create Value v on stack? This could have some really nasty side-effects...

Comment: @Robert:  Yes, `v` exists on the stack.  I don't see why that matters, though, since `v` only exists until the function ends and no pointers or references to `v` are leaked from the function so there's no way to access it once the function returns.

Comment: Right, my bad. I have been writing too much Java lately :)

Answer (score 1):

And change the second printf to use the values of v, not the variable id, type, a.

```
printf("id: %d, type: %c, a: %c \n",v.id,v.type,v.a);
```